# Adjust font-size relatively to original value

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to adjust font-size (or any other css value) inline relatively to the original value specified in external styles sheet? Like so that the first paragraph in the fiddle would actually be `3em * 110% = 3.3em`, not `1.1em` like it is now.

```css
p.a {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<p class="a" style="font-size: 110%">
  adjusted text
</p>
<p class="a">
  normal text
</p>
```

Comment: You're going to have to wrap your <p> tags to achieve this. Inline CSS does not work WITH external CSS, it overrides it based on default values.Adding the inline style you are with your current set up is simply changing the css to `p.a{font-size:110%;}`. By wrapping your paragraphs with a div and giving that div a class to keep things organized (such as "blog-post"), you can set the default font size for everything within that div. Then your inline style will work how you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using calc to multiply the font size:

```css
p.a {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<p class="a" style="font-size: calc(110% * 3)">
  adjusted text
</p>
<p class="a">
  normal text
</p>
```

The second option is to use the em font size value of the common parent element as the multiplier and set the em font size values of the children elements as if 1em = 100% so 1.1em would equal 110%:

```css
.parent {
  font-size: 3em;
}

p.a {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="a" style="font-size: 1.1em">
    adjusted text
  </p>
  <p class="a">
    normal text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the first option, but a) I can do calculation from two relative values myself and hardcode 3.3em and b) I wanted something universal, which I could use without knowing the original value. Unfortunately, I can't do it the second way without some ugly wrapper magic, which I wanted to avoid

Comment: @M.Volf, what do you mean wrappers are ugly? It's not magic..that's how you achieve your goal. Haha.